# Training LSTM model with Sparse labels shape problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

LSTM model to predict Daily Returns of a Stock. I've used `pd.qcut()` to bin the data into quartiles using those quartiles as sparse labels.

I then built the LSTM Model:

```
regressor = Sequential()

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True,
 input_shape = (X_train_scaled_sequence.shape[1], X_train_scaled_sequence.shape[2])))

regressor.add(Dropout(DROUPOUT))


regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(DROUPOUT))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(DROUPOUT))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50))
regressor.add(Dropout(DROUPOUT))

regressor.add(Dense(units = 10, activation='softmax'))

opt = SGD(lr=0.001)

regressor.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), 
optimizer = opt, 
metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])

history = regressor.fit(X_train_scaled_sequence, Y_train_scaled_sequence,
validation_data=(X_val_scaled_sequence, Y_val_scaled_sequence), epochs = EPOCHS, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE)
```

Data Shapes:

```
print(X_train_scaled_sequence.shape)
>>> (2575, 60, 154)
print(Y_train_scaled_sequence.shape)
>>> (2575,)
```

I get this error however,

```
raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

ValueError: Shapes (None, 10) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

Comment: Just to add I've binned the data into deciles and therefore have 10 labels

Comment: im not too good with this stuff but i think the output of your last layer should match you y data, so change  the 10 to 1  in the softmax layer.